# How to handle redirects in curl

Tags: php, curl

So I'm doing a script with curl that logs in into a little application I made.
Right now this is the code I have:

```
<?php


$postData = array(
'name' => 'postmanole',
'password' => 'password',
//'_token' => csrf_token(),
);


$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'http://a.localhost/login',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS=> $postData,
CURLOPT_POST => true,

CURLOPT_POSTREDIR=> CURL_REDIR_POST_ALL ,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
));




$output = curl_exec($ch);

echo $output;

?>
```

It seems to work but the problem is that after login, the user is redirected to a welcome page where the POST method is not supported, so I get that error.

How can I get around this?

My intention is to automatize testing of web applications, any info about this would be useful, I havent found much on the internet.

Thanks in advance

*EDIT*

The error I'm getting is `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.`

Comment: You say you get 'that' error, what error are you precisely getting? I'm guessing that when you've logged in, there is a token that is exchanged on future page requests, how is the token exchange handled?

Comment: there is already bunch of testing tools like selenium, katalon etc. which automates UI testing

Comment: ```the POST method is not supported```. Yes, my application uses tokens but I havent done anything on curl with it

Comment: @siddhesh I know, but that is the challenge

Comment: Is your login response returning the Redirect header ?

Comment: Can you send extra parameter in postdata, and in the login script you can put a condition to check whether its Automation call or not by validating extra parameter,